# Merge dictionaries, change both dict items via merge dict

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two classes with variable dictionaries. I want to merge one into another but when changing data in merged dictionary should update the other.

The overall goal is to use dictionary from the Parent class in a model/view framework where it’s accessed/updated. Since Parent contains the Child instance dictionary; when I update the Parent dict items that correspond to the item in the Child dict; it should update that item in both dictionaries not just the Parent dict. The solution should hopefully be accessing Parent dict directly and not both

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variables = {"item1": 33}

class Child:
    def __init__(self):
        self.variables = {"item2": 23}

class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p = Parent()
        self.c = Child()
   
    def merge(self):
        self.p.variables.update(self.c.variables)

obj = Obj()
obj.merge()
obj.p.variables["item2"] = 1

print(obj.c.variables["item2"]) #should be 1
```

Any ideas what else I could try to change one dictionary but update them both. I could have method that changes
both items in dictionary if exists but I would like to only change one.

Comment: Have you considered `self.p.variables = self.c.variables`? I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. It might help to add the context. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: @wjandrea that only assigns same variables. `self.p `should contain both dictionaries (`self.p` and `self.c`). `self.c` doesn’t change. Since `self.p` contains a dictionary item that exists in `self.c`; In this example `self.p[“item2”] = 1`changes both dictionaries

Comment: What do you mean, "`self.c` doesn’t change"? In your example, a change to `obj.p.variables` should affect `obj.c.variables`.

Comment: Meaning `self.c` only contains “item2”. Running above “item2” is still 23 but should be 1

Comment: Oh OK, so you don't want `obj.c.variables` to take `"item1"`

Comment: I can think of a few different ways to do this, but I'm not sure which is best, or which would even work for you, cause I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish. Could you [edit] and add the context? For reference see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832)

Comment: @wjandrea I tried giving a brief idea of how it’s being used